# Does parenthesis influence the index usage in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I understand that the order of criteria in the where clause does not influence index usage.

Does parenthesis influence the index usage in SQL Server? Is there any example?

Comment: Parentheses will enforce the logical correctness of the query. If the query is not logically correct without parentheses then the usage of indexes is also logically irrelevant.

Comment: what is the motivation for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously.  If I have an index on `(y)` and an expression like this:

```
 where y > 10 and x = 'a' or x = 'c'
```

then no index will be used.

If I put:

```
 where y > 10 and( x = 'a' or x = 'c')
```

Then the index will probably be used.

These do different things, but that is not part of your question.  Parentheses can change the meaning of a SQL statement and that changes the use of indexes.